# Upload a document and fill out list item data in the same form

Tags: document-library, custom-form, file-upload

I am working on a solution where I need to upload a document to a document library, as well as input the item information.

I would like to do this from a single form, as opposed to the Out-of-the-box two step form process, when adding documents to a document-library.

Can any of you suggest a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to achieve it:

1. third-party controls
2. Silverlight control which uses OM - see here an example
   http://priteshdave.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/multiple-upload-with-metadata/
3. ECMA Script to upload and set metadata (for upload see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms456628.aspx and for metadata see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7413/ecma-script-to-update-sharepoint-2010-list-item.aspx)

Comment: Second solution may well be a good solution but no source code is available.

Comment: @Falak: I'm generally looking for sparring on the idea. Not so much how to code it. Since I am still a rookie, my biggest problem is actually being able to "think correctly" about how to approach a solution. I think the Silverlight approach is also the best choice in my situation - alas, I have no experience with Silverlight as of yet. But I guess I am about to get that now ;-)

Comment: @Falak: Have a look here for some more in-depth info on uploading to a doc.lib. with Silverlight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419951/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-using-silverlight-and-c